# How can I record audio along with Aforge player video recording?

Tags: c#, winforms, ffmpeg, aforge, accord.net

My app is playing webcam video using Aforge Plyer. Now I want to record this video. Using Aforge player audio recording is not possible.

Is there any way to record audio separately and merge it with recorded video using Aforge player?

Found that using Direct Show architecture is the way to achieve this. But it will be very difficult to change the architecture at the last time of development. Since I'm unaware with directshow concepts and almost 90 percentage of my project is completed with Aforge player.

My current code is here. It can record video from selected webcam using aforge player. But audio is missing

```
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;

    private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo = null;
    private VideoCaptureDeviceForm captureDevice;
    private Bitmap video;
    private VideoFileWriter FileWriter = new VideoFileWriter();
    private SaveFileDialog saveAvi;

    private void VideoRecord_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        captureDevice = new VideoCaptureDeviceForm();
    }
    private void play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (captureDevice.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
            FinalVideo = captureDevice.VideoDevice;
            FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
            FinalVideo.Start();
        }
    }
    void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (butStop.Text == "Stop Record")
        {
            video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);
        }
        else
        {
            video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();;
        }
    }
    private void Record_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveAvi = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveAvi.Filter = "Avi Files (*.avi)|*.avi";
        if (saveAvi.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int h = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Height;
            int w = captureDevice.VideoDevice.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Width;
            FileWriter.Open(saveAvi.FileName, w, h, 25, VideoCodec.Default, 5000000);
            FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(video);
            butStop.Text = "Stop Record";
        }
    }
    private void stopRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (butStop.Text == "Stop Record")
        {
            butStop.Text = "Stop";
            if (FinalVideo == null)
            { return; }
            if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
            {
                FileWriter.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.FinalVideo.Stop();
            FileWriter.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel please check now

Comment: I have no idea how this lib works but my guess would be that you also need to _explicitely_ select an audio device.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/56454060/2137237 maybe the code in the question can help you.

Comment: Hey man, at this point I suspect you must have had completed your project, so I need some help. My question is that after getting each snapshot instead of recording and , saving to disk, I need to encode and send the data over UDP how can I encode each frame to enough size?